# TypeError: props.logic is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Trying to call a method from the class in my App.js from one of my react components.

The code where I am calling the method is the following:

```
     5 | const Card = props  => (
   6 |   <div className="card"> 
   7 |         <img alt={props.name} src={props.image} id={props.id} className='logic'
>  8 |         onClick= { () => props.logic(props.id) } />
   9 |   </div>
  10 | );
```

The method I am trying to call looks like this:

```
    class App extends Component {
  state = {
    cards,
      score: 0,
      highScore: 0,
      // clickCount: 0,
      winningScore: 16,
      clickedCharacters: []
  };

     logic = id => {
      let clickedCharacters = this.state.cards.clickedCharacters;
      let score = this.state.cards.score;
      let highScore = this.state.cards.highScore

      if (clickedCharacters.includes(id)) {
        alert("Game over, your score is " + this.state.score)
        this.reset();
        return;
      }

      else {
        clickedCharacters.push(id)
        this.setState({
          score: clickedCharacters.length
        })
        if (clickedCharacters.length === 16) {
          alert("You win!");
          return;
        }
        // FIXME: 
        else if (score >= highScore) {
          this.setState({
            highScore: score
          })
        }
        // FIXME:
        // for (let i = clickedCharacters.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
        //   let j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
        //   [clickedCharacters[i], clickedCharacters[j] = clickedCharacters[j], clickedCharacters[i]];
        // }
      }
    }

}
```

I am not getting any errors until I try to click on one the images to call the function.

Render function is the following:

```
render() {
  return(
  <Wrapper>
    <Header score={this.state.score} highscore={this.state.highscore}>Clicky Game</Header>
      <div className="grid">
      {this.state.cards.map(card => (
        <Card
          // clickCount={this.clickCount}
          id={card.id}
          key={card.id}
          image={card.image}
        />
      ))}
    </div>
    <br></br>
  </Wrapper>
  )
}
```

Comment: show how you pass `logic` into `Card`

Comment: Can you please post how do you add `Card` into the `render` function? I'm thinking about maybe `props` has been wrongly passed there. Thanks!

Comment: @norbitrial I added the render function, I think you're on to something

Comment: cards property in state should also be undefined. You need to give it a value when you initialize state.

Comment: @hotpink Could you provide a quick example of how I might do that? Sorry I am new to react

Comment: @hotpink Gotcha. That's a helpful tip for sure. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't pass the `logic` function into `Card`

```js
<Card 
  logic={this.logic}
  id={card.id}
  key={card.id}
  image={card.image}
/>
```

Comment: Yes, that's the thing. Without that, it is just simply `undefined` and that's why it was not a function.

Comment: Awesome, that was it. Thank you much!!